# Adding classpath entry to EquinoxClassLoader for an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, classloader, equinox

I would like to add few classpath entries to EquinoxClassLoader for an eclipse plugin, so that they can be viewed inside my eclipse plugin code. I don't want to change the default class-loading mechanism for the plugin, and do not want to disturb the default class loader being used by the plugin.

Just want to add few classpath entries to the default classloader being used by the plugin. Do we have any hook, where I can get access to the default class loader being used by the plugin thus can add few classpath entries to it.

Comment: I don't see how this would be any different from the normal `Bundle-ClassPath`, `Require-Bundle` and `Import-Package` entries in the MANIFEST.MF. Tell us why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Actually, I want the classpath of the Java project to be visible to the plugin, that the plugin would operate on. Plugin would need to read some of the classes of the java project (classes and referenced classes) as part of its functionalities. So I was thinking that If I can get a hooking point where I can include the output folder of the java project and its referenced classes as the classpath entries to the plugin project, so that the plugin project can see the java project's classpath.

Comment: You use the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) and interfaces such as `IClasspathEntry` to do things like that.